# How to determine number of rows in a merged cell using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, automated-tests, apache-poi

I am using excel to input data for my test automation scripts and I am able read data from excel when i know the exact row and the column to read. The challenge which I am facing is when I have merged cells in the sheet. E.g. [Test data excel sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1lDh.png)

Here ScriptName and Iteration are my primary keys to identify a unique set of data for my script. 
So my question here is:

1. **I want to fetch all the ReferenceSetName with respect to a ScriptName, and Iteration i.e. for Login script, Iteration 1: I have to fetch ABC1 Ref set, ABC2 Ref set, ABC3 Ref set**
2. **I want to fetch all the PackageName with respect to a ScriptName, Iteration, and ReferenceSet i.e. for Login script, Iteration 1, ReferenceSet ABC1 Ref set: I  have to fetch ABC1, ABC2, ABC3**

Currently below is the method - getEntireCellValue() I am using to fetch the data from excel and I need help to solve the above 2 problems. Any kind of support is really appreciated.

```
public void getExcelRowNum() {
    boolean found = false;
    String scriptCell = null, iterationCell = null;
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Iterator iterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = (Row) iterator.next();
            scriptCell = row.getCell(1).toString().trim();
            iterationCell = row.getCell(2).toString().trim();
            if (row.getCell(2).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC)
                iterationCell = iterationCell.substring(0, iterationCell.indexOf(".")).trim();
            if ((scriptCell.equals(scriptName) && iterationCell.equals(String.valueOf(iteration).trim()))
                    || (scriptCell.equals(scriptName) && Integer.parseInt(iterationCell) == iteration)) {
                rowNum = row.getRowNum();

                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rowNum == -1 || found == false)
            throw new Exception("Please check the test name: " + scriptName + " or the iteration: " + iteration
                    + " in the test data sheet");

        row = sheet.getRow(0);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getExcelColNum(String colName) {
    boolean found = false;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName.trim())) {
                col_Num = i;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (col_Num == -1 || found == false)
            throw new Exception("Please check the column name: " + colName + " in the test data sheet");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getCell() {
    try {
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
        cell = row.getCell(col_Num);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    //Prior to calling this method. I am connecting to the excel sheet which 
    is in .xlsx or xls format
    public String getEntireCellValue(String sheetName, String colName) {
            try {
                sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);           
                getExcelRowNum();
                getExcelColNum(colName);
                getCell();
                if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING)
                    return cell.getStringCellValue().trim();
                else if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK)
                    return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
         }
    }

    public int getNumOfMergedRows() {
        int rowsMerged = 0;
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
                CellRangeAddress range = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
                if (range.getFirstRow() <= rowNum && range.getLastRow() >= 
                rowNum) {
                    ++rowsMerged;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Number of rows merged are: " + rowsMerged);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rowsMerged;
    }
```

P.S. What I am doing here is, I am trying to fetch the number of merged rows for a script e.g. 6 rows are merged for Login script and then find number of cells inside those 6 rows to get the reference set name (3 cells). 
Note: When I call the above method - getNumOfMergedRows() to determine number of rows merged for Login script, I am getting 4 as output instead of 6.

Comment: What is the value of rowNum variable in your if condition?

Comment: Added the code which i use to determine the rowNum. Note: All the variables are instance variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will determine the number of merged cells in a column - colName, with begining row as startingRow

```
public int getNumOfMergedRows(String colName, int startingRow) {
    int rowsMerged = 0, col = 0;
    XSSFRow mergedRow = null;
    XSSFCell mergedCell = null;
    try {
        col = getExcelColNum(colName);
        for (int i = startingRow + 1; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
            mergedRow = sheet.getRow(i);
            mergedCell = mergedRow.getCell(col);
            if (mergedCell.getCellTypeEnum() == null || mergedCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK)
                rowsMerged++;
            else
                break;
        }
        rowsMerged++;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info(rowsMerged + " rows are merged in columne" + colName + " for " + scriptName + " script");
    return rowsMerged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample code which takes the fiel as input.It will count the values in 3rd column for all values and stores it in a map. It does so by counting the blank values in excel file and reset the counter at each valid value

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFile(new File("excelstack.xlsx"));
    }
    public static void readFile(File file) {

        try {

            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

            Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

            int coltocheck=1;
            int counter=1;
            String currentitem="";
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();                                              
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();                                  
                   if(currentCell.getCellTypeEnum()==CellType.BLANK ) { 
                            if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==coltocheck)
                                    map.put(currentitem, counter++);
                    }                    
                    else if(currentCell.getCellTypeEnum()==CellType.STRING && currentCell.getColumnIndex()==coltocheck) {
                            currentitem=currentCell.getStringCellValue();                       
                            counter=1;
                            map.put(currentitem, counter++);

                    }
                }                                                
            } 
           for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> m:map.entrySet())
               System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {                     
        }


    }
}
```